# Unable to step into lru_cache'_lru_cache_wrapper

Tags: python, lru, functools

For some reason I am unable to step into the _lru_cache_wrapper's code at all.

I see that the lru_cache decorator returns a closure with _lru_cache_wrapper within functools.py. However when I put a breakpoint in _lru_cache_wrapper's code it never gets triggered. I have even put a print() statement which doesn't appear to get hit. I am really puzzled by this since the lru_cache code hits the breakpoint but not _lru_cache_wrapper.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def foo():
    print('foo')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
    print(foo.cache_info())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version in `functools.py` doesn't get used. It's [replaced](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Lib/functools.py#L598) by a version written in C from `_functools`:

```
try:
    from _functools import _lru_cache_wrapper
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why the python code is still there?

Comment: @k-war: IIRC, the stated reasons for keeping the Python versions of C-accelerated code around are to have a second version to test the C against, and for the benefit of other Python implementations that can't use the C version.

Comment: This also explains something which was puzzling me. In the Python code `_lru_cache_wrapper` is clearly a function rather than a class definition, but when you evaluate `type(f)` on a decorated function you get `<class 'functools._lru_cache_wrapper'>`.